# How does protecting trade work in Conquest of Paradise?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv, conquest-of-paradise

In my current game, I'm playing as Bohemia and I own colonial provinces in North America. Until the recent patch 1.4, released together with Conquest of Paradise, I used light ships to “protect trade” in Chesapeake Bay.

But after the patch, my colonies were converted to separate colonial nations. Now, when my fleet is in Europe, I can't even select the option to protect trade in Chesapeake Bay. But when I move my fleet there, I can now select that option, but it deselects itself after one day. Note that I also have a trader in Chesapeake Bay.

Even more confusing is the new Western Europe trade node: it behaves the same as Chesapeake Bay to me, but apparently some AI countries managed to have their fleets there (they are listed in the node screen).

So, my question is, can I send my ships to protect trade in trade nodes where I only have colonies or in the Western Europe trade node, which doesn't have any provinces at all? If I can do that, how?

(I didn't actually have the Conquest of Paradise DLC, these changes are from the 1.4 patch.)

Comment: This is likely bugged somehow. As Portugal and Castille, I had no trouble protecting the Western Europe Trade Node. So it might have something to do with the location of your country. Same goes for Colonial Trade Nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Now I'm playing another game and it looks like protecting trade in a node requires either an active merchant or a province in that node (province of a colony is not enough).

---

Original answer:

I continued playing and now I *can* send my trading fleets to those trade nodes. It seems the issue fixed itself.

Comment: Perhaps your "trade distance" has improved? You can only send merchants/protect trade up to a certain distance from your capital, is that right?

Comment: From what I read the issue is connected to supply ship range, which seems to be fixed at 150. Not sure though. Some people had luck moving their ships close to the trade node first, at which point they could actually protect it.